# Parse Error Sends Error to Send PDF

Tags: php

Ok Everything sends Fine, except the PDF file i browsed in from ma computer.

My code looks like this now.

```
<?php
$ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
$hostname = gethostbyaddr($ip);

$email_to = "a@domain.com";
$email_subject = "My subject";
$fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
$institution = $_POST['institution'];
$month = $_POST['month'];
$Day = $_POST['Day'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$courses = $_POST['courses'];
$marital_status = $_POST['marital_status'];
$cover_letter = $_POST['cover_letter'];
$file_name = $_FILES['resume']['name'];
$file_size = $_FILES['resume']['size'];
$file_type = $_FILES['resume']['type'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'];

$email_msg = "IP: $ip\n Host Name: $hostname\n Name in Full : $fullname\n Institution: $institution\n DOB : $month/$Day/$year\n Courses: $courses\n Marital Status: $marital_status\n Cover Letter : $cover_letter\n\n";

$file = fopen($tmp_name,'rb');
$data = fread($file,filesize($tmp_name));
fclose($file);

$semi_rand     = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
"Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" ;
$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
"-{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
$email_msg  . "\n\n";
$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type: {$file_type};\n" .
" name=\"{$tmp_name}\"\n" .
"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
" filename=\"{$tmp_name}\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
$data . "\n\n" .
"-{$mime_boundary}-\n";




$sendmemail = @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_msg, $headers);

if($sendmemail)
    {

                echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                window.alert('Registeration Complete')
                window.location.href='[url]';
                </SCRIPT>"); 
    }

?>
```

The code now works 100%, but It sends only the parameters captured and no PDF file.
where exactly am i getting it all wrong?

Comment: The file you're trying to open does not exist. Fix that first.

Comment: i browse it from my desktop. or you mean it should get the extension of file?

Comment: The error says the file you're trying to open with `fopen()` doesn't exist.

Comment: @thebluefox, the File is on my Desktop. I am trying to browse from my desktop, attach and email to another mail.

Comment: @RealMary make a `file_exists()` check before trying to open the file. The name is probably wrong.

Comment: @RealMary - Look at the file path it references in the error - you can clearly see it's not, at that point, trying to open the file on your desktop. As you've uploaded it it's in temp storage, and you need to make sure you're opening the right file from there.

Comment: same error i get

Comment: Validate & Sanitize your inputs (`$_POST`, `$_FILES`).

Answer (score 1):

You try to open the **original** filename which is not the actual filename on the server.

Wrong: `$zap = dirname(__FILE__) . $file_name;`

You already have that variable but assign it wrong to `$zap`, instead use the `tmp_name`:

```
$zap = dirname(__FILE__) . $tmp_name;
```

Consider http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 problems here.

Firstly, you are [reporting errors](http://nyphp.org/PHundamentals/7_PHP-Error-Handling) to the stdout stream. This is very bad practice on a production system - it can leak all sorts of details about the internals of your system and makes for a bad user experience.

The second problem is that you are not detecting and handling the error conditions in your code. Unless you expect the recipient of the email to fix the problem then you should be verifying that key operations have worked successfully (usually anything which talks to components outside of PHP - database, files, network etc)

The third problem is that the files you are trying to access from the script are not in the locations you specify or are not readable by the uid the script is running as. Since you are using the supplied file name and not the filename generated by PHP to hold the upload - then the former is the cause.

You are also trying to read the file from the directory in which your PHP script resides. It will not be put there. Use the path in $_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'];

If you want to retain uploaded files then use [move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) but [DO NOT PUT THE UPLOADED FILE ANYWHERE IT IS ACCESSIBLE VIA THE WEBSERVER](http://symcbean.blogspot.co.uk/2016/06/local-file-inclusion-why-everything-you.html)

`$headers .=` should be `$headers=`

You should also be using \r\n for the line endings in your SMTP headers.

Comment: I have editted it now, it sends but doesnt send the PDF file. other information it captures, it sends to the mail, but the PDF is missing.

Comment: So continue debugging - look at the source of the email and see what's actually there.